# Why does `String.interpolate` behave differently depending on the sequence?

Tags: ruby, quotes

With the following code, I expect to see `'test-keyword'`, but I don't:

```
line_item = "\#{item[‘value’][‘keyword’]}"
item['value'] # => {..., "keyword"=>"test-keyword", ...}
String.interpolate {line_item} # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `‘value’'
```

However, if I change the value for `line_item`, interpolate, then change back, I get a different result:

```
line_item = "\#{item['value']}"
String.interpolate {line_item}
# => "{\"bot_client_id\"=>\"aiaas-1409611358153-user-0012\", \"recurring\"=>true, \"recurring_natural_language\"=>\"every day\", \"time_string\"=>\"9:16am\", \"ti_Angeles\", \"via\"=>\"sms\", \"keyword\"=>\"test-keyword\", \"status\"=>\"active\", \"created_time\"=>1453620894000, \"process\"=>\"unstarted\"}"
```

In the above, `interpolate` works successfully by just changing `line_item`. However,

```
line_item = "\#{item['value']['keyword']}"
String.interpolate {line_item} # => "test-keyword"
```

Now it works. In the first pass, `item['value']['keyword']` fails; second time, it works.

My intended behavior is to have it work as the second time, but I keep erroring with an undefined local variable. What do I need to do?

Comment: There is no such method in core Ruby. If you are using a particular library/framework/script, write so.

Answer (score 0):

Change the quotes `’` in `"\#{item[‘value’][‘keyword’]}"` to `'`.

Comment: Hm apostrophe for testing is user input and so used the format sent from the device. Looks like I may need to change all apostrophes.